# Getting an error trying to convert a pdf into a list so I can search the document

Tags: c#, list, search, pdfpig

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using UglyToad.PdfPig;

namespace TrainingProject
{
    class Program
    {
        public static object GetPages { get; private set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var pdf = PdfDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\name\desktop\blahblahblah.pdf"))

            {
                foreach (var page in pdf.GetPages())

                {
                    // Extract based on grouping letters into words.
                    var pageText = string.Join(" ", page.GetWords());

                }

                bool found = false;

                {
                    var pages = pdf.GetPages();
                    GetPages.add.ToList(pages);
                    string pageText = pages[0].Text;
                    if (pageText.Contains("|BRE|"))
                    {
                        found = true;
                    }
                }

                if (found)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Text Found");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Text not found");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

}

I'm using pdfPig library to convert a pdf to text and then I want to convert that string to a list so that I can search the list for a specific string. The error is on the GetPages.add.ToList(pages); statement.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and what does the error say ? also if you have all words into a single string you can look inside that, why do you need to convert it to a list ?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had included the error message - 'object' does not contain a definition for 'add' and no accessible extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mauricio, no need for a list if you just want to search:

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\name\desktop\blahblahblah.pdf"))
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (Page page in document.GetPages())
    {
        if (page.Text.Contains("|BRE|"))
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text Found");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text not found");
    }
}
```

And if you do want to play with Lists in .NET, start with [Generic Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/collections):

```
    List<Page> pagesOfInterest = new List<string>();
    foreach (Page page in document.GetPages())
    {
        if (page.Text.Contains("|BRE|"))
        {
            pagesOfInterest.Add(page);
        }
    }
```

Comment: converting to a list was suggested by a colleague. Eventually I want to be able to convert hundreds of pdfs to text and then search the first page for a string. He suggested that converting to a list would make that easier. I'm a total beginner with C# so I'm just muddling through as best I can.

Comment: trying different approaches never hurts, just make sure you understand the pros/cons of each.